# How to realize a performant batch image convert for huge quantity?

Tags: php, linux, cron, command-line-interface, batch-processing

I'm syncing at the moment some files at night from Server A to Server B with a Cronjob (PHP CLI) that uses LFTP and writes the log of it into a special mysql table. The images I sync are tiff files.

I'm using ImageMagick to convert this pictures into some preview-png pictures with some extras (watermarking, resizing, clipping paths and embedding a color profile)

Full commands [here](https://gist.github.com/CodeBrauer/5ff683d514b14f7bcd99).

---

So how would be the "best" way to convert more than 100 (sometimes there are 10 - sometimes there are 250+) images at the best way?

My script should be safe - so every tiff-files always has web-previews. So I'm checking all images and if every images has its preview-pngs - if not - generate them!

I don't to overload this post with code so here is a **[gist](https://gist.github.com/CodeBrauer/edab1838c0aa5b33cedd)**

The script will be running as simple cron with php-fcgi.

This script is now very "slow". One ImageMagick-command takes about 1-2 seconds - sometimes more than 15sec (big file, complex paths). - Any `shell_exec` holds the script for the time it finished the command.

Is there some way to make this more efficient?

Note: I can't install extra software on the server.

Comment: Your first 2 commands are almost identical, except the second one has a `-resize` at the end. You could maybe discard the first command and just use the second command, inserting a `-write out.png` immediately prior to the `-resize`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for that hint. Didn't know that was even possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need the images right away then you could put the image conversions in a queue (something like [Beanstalk](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd)) and let that handle the long and intensive operations.

Comment: I forget to add something: I can't install extra software on the server. It is not my server - but beanstalk may work

Comment: If you cannot install software then you could always use a pure PHP/database combo. Shouldn't be too hard; insert jobs into the database queue, have a cron that runs frequently that looks to see if it isn't already processing an image, if not then it grabs the next available job.

Comment: Okay - I will try the pure PHP/DB Combo. As you said - should be quickly done.